# A Simple Mac OS X Sound App

Tags: macos, audio, input, driver

I'm new to XCode and I have this project that I want to get on with. I want to create a small app for OS X that can get an audio input from whatever output and input device I set on **System Preferences\Sound** and output it to a specific then play that sound to a different device on **System Preferences\Sound\Output**.

I'm fairly new to coding Mac apps (in XCode probably) and please don't take me for granted. If you need any more clarification about my question, please do so in the comments below so that I can provide you with more detail as to what I want to do.

Also, please include a set of programming languages where I can achieve such a goal. (Eg; Objective-C, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you're new to it you're best off sticking with Objective-C for the moment, it's the platform standard and whilst there's plenty of other resources every road leads back to Cocoa eventually. I'm making an assumption you've programmed before but if you need a ground up on Cocoa/Obj-C [there's a good one on Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) to get you up and running.

A good starting point would be the [CoreAudio overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) which explains about how Cocoa handles sound in/out, and then there's an Apple coded example [at CAPlaythrough](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004443), which is about 3 years out of date but should be a good starting point on looking at the way CoreAudio works and how to get the input to head to the output.